# How can I create a multiple choice Q in Qualtrics but make one of the possible answers a drop down list?

Tags: qualtrics

How can I create a multiple choice question in Qualtrics but make one of the possible answers a drop down list? For example, Dog (answer choice #1), Cat (answer choice #2), Other (answer choice #3) but with drop down list of other choices to choose from. Is this even possible in Qualtrics?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible by default in Qualtrics. Though this is certainly something that could be built using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will go another route with this particular survey question.